# Breeze not supported new EntityFramework version

Tags: c#, entity-framework, angularjs, breeze

I am learning angular-breeze for my next application. I want to use Entity Framework, but i am getting some errors while adding **breeze.WebApi** package from NuGet.

> Install failed. Rolling back...
>
> Install-Package : Updating 'EntityFramework 6.0.1' to 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' failed. Unable t
>   o find a version of 'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact' that is compatible with 'EntityFramewor
>   k 5.0.0'.
>
> At line:1 char:16
>   + install-package <<<<  **breeze.WebApi**
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.Install 
>      PackageCommand

Comment: Breeze does not yet support ef6 as clearly shown everywhere, just google it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF6 is now supported as of Breeze 1.4.5

----------- OLD POST ---------------

We will be adding EF6 support in our next release.  This will be out within a few weeks.

Comment: any idea why I am still getting this exception? `Installing 'Breeze.WebApi 1.4.7'. Successfully installed 'Breeze.WebApi 1.4.7'. Install failed. Rolling back... Install-Package : Updating 'EntityFramework 6.0.2' to 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' failed. Unable to find a version of 'EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact' that is compatible with 'EntityFramework 5.0.0'`.

Comment: OK, my guess is that we don't need to install `Breeze.WebApi` anymore, instead we install `HotTowel.Angular.Breeze`. Am I right?

Comment: HotTowel.Angular.Breeze installs Breeze.Client (≥ 1.4.5)
Breeze.Server.WebApi2 (≥ 1.4.5)
HotTowel.Angular (≥ 2.0.2)
Breeze.Angular.Directives (≥ 1.2.0)     https://www.nuget.org/packages/hottowel.angular.breeze